# How can I display messages in Apple Mail thread by newest first

Tags: mail.app, email, monterey

I am using MacOS 12.2.1, In Apple MAil, when clicking on an email, it displays all the messages sent back and forth in the thread, but the newest message is at the bottom, rather than the newest one at the top.

I can resort the emails by date, but I cant see how to resort the emails in the thread so that it shows the newest message at the top of the thread.

How do I resort them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be set in Mail preferences under "Viewing", turn on "Show most recent message at the top".

[image: Mail Preferences "Viewing" circle around Show most recent message at the top]